# How does these services get passed into the controller? version 1.0.8

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dependency-injection

I got a new job, and took over some systems from some people that isn't here anymore. The version is all the way down to 1.0.8 in angular.js though, and the implementations they have been using seems to be what the community has been saying not to do since forever.

My question is, how do the vvscontroller get the services in as arguments?

I have been trying to grep through the project for any reference for the args: `ElReport, ElRow, User, PriorReports, Documentation` but it seems like they just magically get parsed in, then i searched for dependency injection, looking if i could find any implementations of the different providers the angular.js mentions, but i can only find the routeProvider and maybe something else that didn't look like it was configured.

So there is a lot of code where i don't think its related - but it might be but obviously i cannot post the entire code here. I was thinking it might be configured into the HTML or something but when i grep for `ng-controller` i don't find anything related to the `PlumbingCtrl`, but i just can't quite point it out. Can anyone tell me in what direction i should be looking?? what classes are likely to be used in order to achive this?

> app.js

```
angular.module('housingevaluation', ['ngRoute', 'housingServices', 'ngUpload', 'angucomplete', 'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker', 'ngResource', 'fcsa-number']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: HomeCtrl}).when('/vvs/:reportId', {templateUrl: 'partials/plumbing.html', controller: PlumbingCtrl}). 
...more controllers + some config that does something with http/https(don't think thats related)
```

> services.js

```
angular.module('housingServices', ['ngResource']).
        factory('ElReport', function($resource) {
        return $resource('reports/el/:id', {id: '@Id'}, {
            query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false},
            get: {method: 'GET'},
            save: {method: 'POST'},
            completeReport: {method: 'POST', url: 'reports/el/:id/complete'},
            reopenReport: {method: 'POST', url: 'reports/el/:id/reopen'},
            queryPlumbing: {method: 'GET', isArray: false},
            createCopy: {method: 'POST', url: 'reports/el/:id/reevaluation'},
            createRealCopy: {method: 'POST', url: 'reports/el/:id/copy'},
            markBilled: {method: 'POST', url: 'reports/el/:id/markBilled'}
        });
    }).
...some more factories (Documentation, User, etc.)
...some more directives
```

> vvscontroller.js

```
function PlumbingCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $location, ElReport, ElRow, User, PriorReports, Documentation) {
...
}
```

> index.html

```
<html ng-app>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `module housingevaluation` is your root module of Angularjs application. All your services like `ElReport` , `Documentation` etc are part of `module housingServices` and `module housingServices` is injected to your root module `module housingevaluation`. It means all your services from `module housingServices` are accessible in `module housingevaluation`. And your all controllers are part of your root module that is `module housingevaluation`. Thats why all services from `module housingServices` are accessible in your controller.

One more thing is `services.js` and `vvscontroller.js` must be added in `index.html` before `app.js`.

---

EDIT :
Somewhere in your code PlumbingCtrl must have added to your root module housingevaluation. While adding the controller to module you can give order of depedancy injection for PlumbingCtrl. like this...

```
angular.module('housingevaluation')
  .controller('PlumbingCtrl', [ '$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'ElReport', 'ElRow', 'User', 'PriorReports', 'Documentation', function PlumbingCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $location, ElReport, ElRow, User, PriorReports, Documentation) {
    ...
}]);
```

Now while defining your controller you have to follow the same order for injecting the factories/services. like this...

```
function PlumbingCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $location, ElReport, ElRow, User, PriorReports, Documentation) { ... }
```

---

It may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're completely right about you're assertions, what i am wondering though is that the services that get passed into the controller is in a specific order, and the order isn't the order in which the factories are being declared. So some logic is missing where a $injector or something else registers in which order the controller should receive the services.

Comment: The order of factories  in module housingServices does not mater at all, with the order of injecting that factories/services in controller PlumbingCtrl.

Comment: Yeah. But do you know how the order could be set? how someone would do that?

Comment: I have edited the answer. I hope it will answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

you need to inject your controller in angularjs app module

```
  angular.module('housingServices').controller('PlumbingCtrl', PlumbingCtrl);
PlumbingCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'ElReport', 'ElRow', 'User', 'PriorReports', 'Documentation'];
function PlumbingCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $location, ElReport, ElRow, User, 
PriorReports, Documentation) {
   ...
          }
```

Comment: Thanks for you're response, it is true that it should be like you used it instead, what i am wondering though is why my code works even without that.